# Relating graph theory and recurrence relations

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, graph-theory, recurrence-relations

I have this assignment problem and its solution.

Question:

Suppose you are given a pile of $n$ stones. At each step, you are allowed to separate a pile of $k$ stones into two piles of $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$ stones. Obviously, $k_{1} + k_{2} = k$. On doing this, you earn $k_{1} * k_{2}$ dollars. 
What is the maximum amount of money you can earn starting with a pile of $n$ stones? Explain your answer.

Suggested solution(Using graph theory):

One can earn at most $\frac{n(n – 1)}{2}$ dollars.

1. Represent each stone as a vertex in a complete graph $K_{n}$.
2. Two vertices representing two stones are connected if the stones are in the same pile.
3. In the beginning, every stone is in the same pile as every other stone, so there are $\frac{n(n – 1)}{2}$ edges in the graph.
4. Separating a pile of $k$ stones into two piles of $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$ stones corresponds to removing some edges from the graph. The number of edges removed is exactly $k_{1} * k_{2}$.
5. The maximum amount of money one can earn is when the stones are separated into piles with single stone, that is, when all the edges are removed.
6. Since the number of edges in $K_{n}$ is $\frac{n(n – 1)}{2}$, this is the maximum amount one can earn.

As I was still quite new to graph theory(and its subsequent combinatorial thinking), I thought of it as a calculus problem instead, and tried writing a suitable recurrence relation. As a calculus problem, the way we split the pile would matter,splitting up the pile as equally as possible in each recursive step should yield the greatest product hence the greatest amount of money in my opinion, not sure if the graph theory solution, which shows the final outcome instead of the process, has accounted for the sequence of splitting.

The recurrence for $f(n)$, which will get us the maximum amount of money, consists of 2 parts:

For an even number $n$ which is expressed as $2k$:$$f(2k)=k^{2}+f(k)+f(k)$$

For an odd number $n$ which is expressed as $2k+1$: $$f(2k+1)=k(k+1)+f(k)+f(k+1)$$

Combining the 2 results to recreate $f(n)$ in terms of $n$: 
$$f(n)=\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil +f(\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor)+f(\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil)$$

Theoretically, since the suggested answer to this question is $\frac{n(n – 1)}{2}$, I am interested to know whether it is possible to deduce the final closed form expression for this recurrence. This means to say that it is possible to solve this new problem:

Given the recurrence $$f(n)=\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil +f(\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor)+f(\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil)$$, subject to

$$f(0)=0, f(1)=0$$, show that $$f(n)=\frac{n(n – 1)}{2}$$.

However, I do not know many numerical properties that relate to floor and ceiling functions because I'm not a Mathematics Major, and most of them that I have found online either relate to some series or some inequality, neither of which actually allows me to prove a precise equality statement. May I know if my initial intuition about the problem is right? If it is indeed right, is it actually possible to deduce that the closed form expression of this recurrence to be the suggested answer?

Comment: Are you explicitly ruling out proofs which case-split on whether $n$ is even or odd?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Nope, in fact I'm asking about proofs that case-split, that's what my alternative solution is asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Given the recurrence $$f(n)=\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor \left\lceil \frac{n}{2} \right\rceil +f\left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor\right)+f\left(\left\lceil \frac{n}{2} \right\rceil\right)$$ subject to $$f(0)=0, f(1)=0$$show that $$f(n)=\frac{n(n – 1)}{2}$$

Proof by strong induction: suppose $f(i) = \frac12 i(i-1)$ for all $0 \le i < n$, and that $n \ge 2$ (so that $\left\lceil \frac{n}{2} \right\rceil < n$). Then if $n$ is even we have $$f(n) = \frac{n^2}{4} + 2f\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) = \frac{n^2}{4} + \frac{n(n-2)}{4} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$ and if $n$ is odd we have $$\begin{eqnarray}
f(n) &=& \frac{(n-1)}{2} \frac{(n+1)}{2} + f\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right) + f\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right) \\
&=& \frac{(n-1)(n+1)}{4} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{(n-1)}{2} \frac{(n-3)}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{(n+1)}{2} \frac{(n-1)}{2} \\
&=& \frac{n-1}{2} \left(\frac{2n+2}{4} + \frac{n-3}{4} + \frac{n+1}{4} \right) \\
&=& \frac{n(n-1)}{2}
\end{eqnarray}$$

---

Note, however, that this doesn't prove that $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ is the solution to the original problem, because although my intuition agrees with yours that

> splitting up the pile as equally as possible in each recursive step should yield the greatest product hence the greatest amount of money in my opinion

that needs proof. Again, we can use strong induction. Suppose again that $f(i) = \frac12 i(i-1)$ for all $0 \le i < n$, and that $n \ge 2$. Then $$\begin{eqnarray}f(n) &=& \max_k k(n-k) + f(k) + f(n-k) \\
&=& \max_k k(n-k) + \frac{k(k-1)}{2} + \frac{(n-k)(n-k-1)}{2} \\
&=& \max_k \frac{2k(n-k) + k(k-1) + (n-k)(n-k-1)}{2} \\
&=& \max_k \frac{n^2 - n}{2} \\
&=& \frac{n^2 - n}{2}
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: Thanks for the good proof. I didn’t really thought of using Induction because I was more caught up with figuring the answer incrementally from my solution and just results related to the context instead of “proving that an answer works”. Just a small question, for the recurrence dealing with odd n, is there a general formula to equate $\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \rfloor$ to any term with n for any k? It seems to work well for odd and even but I don’t know about general and where to find related rules regarding this.

Comment: Also, while you have proven that the recurrence arrives at the same conclusion, do you have the reason why the graph theory example made it look like any sequence of splitting the piles into 2(and eventually into single stones) would work, while calculus has a very definitive way of achieving that same maximal?

Comment: $\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \rfloor$ is much easier when working with integers than with reals. Specifically, if $n$ and $k$ are both integers then $\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \rfloor = \frac{n - (n \bmod k)}{k}$, so you can case split into $k$ cases.

Comment: As to "*calculus has a very definitive way of achieving that same maximal*", why do you say that? The proof in the second half of the answer shows that the way you split the piles doesn't matter: for any $k$ you get $\frac{n^2-n}{2}$.

Comment: Oh ok, I missed that out, anyway so am I right to conclude it is essential for us to prove the fact that the recurrence reduces to $\frac {(n)(n-1)}{2} $ before we use it in the 2nd half to prove that however way we split it doesn't matter?

Comment: Proof by induction typically requires you to know the answer in advance. If you assume that $f$ is a quadratic then it has to be $f(n) = \alpha n(n-1)$ since $f(0) = f(1) = 0$, and you could try working through the induction and seeing what it tells you about $\alpha$...

Comment: Hmm so in the progress of knowing the answer in advance, it's something like first working with what small information you have ... then try "guessing" the answer, and when you are somewhat confident, run an induction to check if it's true?

Comment: That's generally how maths works. It's just not how it's presented and taught.

Comment: Do you by any chance have any book recommendations for graph theory and combinatorics to strengthen my concepts(preferably with practice problems and solutions). I'm studying for a Discrete Mathematics exam which is around 4 weeks away.

Comment: No. You could try asking in chat.